# How do I make a camera that follows my Player?

Tags: java, camera, game-physics, slick2d

I have a player class, and it's x, and y positions are manipulated with a xPos and yPos, and I want to create a camera that follows the player.

So far I've tried this:

Camera class:

```
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;

public class Camera {

    public int offsetMaxX;
    public int offsetMaxY;
    public int offsetMinX;
    public int offsetMinY;

    public int camX;
    public int camY;

    private Player player;

    public Camera(Player p) {

        //Setting offset max's and minimums
        offsetMaxX = 0;
        offsetMaxY = 0;
        offsetMinX = 0;
        offsetMinY = 0;

        player = p;

    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc) {

        camX = player.xPos - (gc.getWidth() / 2);
        camY = player.yPos - (gc.getHeight() / 2);

    }

}
```

And my render function in my main class is:

```
@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {

    //Translate to camera X and Y
    g.translate(-camera.camX, -camera.camY);

    //Scaling map
    g.scale(3, 3);
    //Rendering map
    try {
        mapRender.render();
    } catch (SlickException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Draw player
    player1.drawPlayer(g);

}
```

This works, but the camera moves slower than the player does. How could I fix this code, or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. When drawing my player, I did

```
g.translate(.5, .5);
```

So when positioning my camera, I had to do

```
camX = ((player.xPos * 1.5f)) - (gc.getWidth() / 2);
camY = (player.yPos * 1.5f) - (gc.getHeight() / 2);
```